# Drop a hector virtual keyspace

Tags: java, cassandra, hector

My team has found problems when we drop and create keyspaces in Cassandra regularly.  I found that Hector has the concept of a virtual keyspace.  It seems like it would fit our needs, except the documentation didn't describe how to drop a virtual keyspace.  Does Hector have an easy way to do this or do I need to crawl through the column families and delete rows keys with the virtual prefix?